# Importing Headers class (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm learning from [this](https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/04/02/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-6-consuming-real-data-with-http/) tutorial in order to make an ajax request. It uses a class named Headers but misses an import statement for that.

```
Injectable()
export class PeopleService{
  private baseUrl: string = 'http://swapi.co/api';
  constructor(private http : Http){
  }

  getAll(): Observable<Person[]>{
    let people$ = this.http
      .get(`${this.baseUrl}/people`, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
      .map(mapPersons);
      return people$;
  }

  private getHeaders(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    return headers;
  }

  // other code...
}
```

Does somebody know where the Headers class is declared in order to import it?

Comment: `import { ..., Headers } from '@angular/http';` Is it a base class in Angular http. There is a link to all the source code in the article. https://github.com/Vintharas/angular2-step-by-step-06-consuming-real-data-with-http/blob/master/src/app/people.service.ts

Comment: @NicoVanBelle great! Please rewrite this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You're welcome. And thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It imports the `Headers` class declared in the Angular HTTP library:

```
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

There is a link in the article that points you to the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/Vintharas/angular2-step-by-step-06-consuming-real-data-with-http/blob/master/src/app/people.service.ts).